# how to code the sensor to stop the motors when the color red is detected?

Tags: arduino, motor

[image]

Any idea how to get this circuit working with two motors working?

[image]

Comment: The positive terminals of the motors are unpowered and your anti parallel diode is backwards.

Comment: Also your 9V battery is connected to the 5V rail of the arduino, which will probably destroy it.

Comment: So any ideas on how to get it working, thanks btw

Comment: Draw a proper schematic. Code.  To get it to work, you have to have a correct circuit AND correct code.  No way we can help without either.

Comment: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/lI01PWCuYKm-copy-of-ultrasonic-sensor-and-dc-motor-/editel?sharecode=9rpH2cEEy5ZS3sednXx1pMq5Y3m0SIMgNG_fsAlMlvE                               I know I have been asking so that what I got so far, all I need to know is how to get the sensor to stop the motors when it sees the color red.   Thanks again

Comment: You have asked the same question in the title, the question and the comments. If you can't give us a schematic AND code, we cannot help you.

Comment: // C++ code
//
void setup()
{
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
long dur;
long dis;
long tocm;
  
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
dur=pulseIn(4,HIGH);
tocm=microsecondsToCentimeters(dur);
  if(tocm<=15)
  {
    digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  }
  
}
long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}

Comment: sorry I am new to this but I figure it out here is the code and the schemairc

Comment: [Edit] your question to add your code. And explain to us **how** you expect your ultrasonic sensor to detect colors. Can you hear colors? Does the sky *sound* blue to you?

Answer (score 2):

Fritzing's don't get a lot of love around here as they're confusing to understand electronically. I see the appeal for assembly as a beginner but schematics will help you learn electronics properly. Fritzings are to electrical engineering as Ikea assembly pictures are to mechanical engineering.

With that in mind I have prepared a schematic of the motors and driver transistor ONLY, and indicated how they would connect to your controller. I have substituted light bulbs for motors since our builtin schematic editor doesn't have motors as an option, but the general idea is there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frasuT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>